# How to convert form tag into form_open in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, form-helpers

How to write this code

```
<form action="http://<?php echo site_url();?>/loader/login_screen_flow" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="login_data">
```

to

```
<?form_open(........)?>
```

format by using form helpers. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: User guide http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$attributes = array('name' => 'login_data');

echo form_open_multipart('loader/login_screen_flowd', $attributes);
```

**Outputs**

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="http:/example.com/index.php/loader/login_screen_flowd"  name="login_data" enctype="multipart/form-data"/>
```

Load form helper as well `$this->load->helper('form');`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$attr = array('name' => 'login_data');
echo form_open_multipart('loader/login_screen_flowd', $attr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try as below :

```
$attribute = array('name'=>'login_data','class'=>'email','id'=>'myform');
echo form_open_multipart('loader/login_screen_flowd', $attribute);
```